# OSM tile server -- too many highway labels

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm running a local OSM tile server.  I've combined three pbfs (three neighboring states) using osmconvert, then loaded them into postgis database:

```
osm2pgsql --slim -d gis --hstore --multi-geometry --tag-transform-script openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.lua --style openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style  
combined_areas.pbf
```

then generated the style.xml `carto project.mml > style.xml` I did not make any changes to this style file.  The style looks the same as the standard style on openstreetmaps.org (which is what I want) except that there are way way too many road labels, especially at lower zoom levels. How can I fix this?

[image]